# The renamed files with Workspace.Merge Method

Tags: c#, tfs, tfvc

I'm using the Workspace.Merge method to perform a merge, but when I specify the MergeOptionsEX.baseless, the state of the renamed files in the source version is changed to create a branch in the destination version.

Baseless option links two versions if it doen't exit. So I changed this option to none, the problem of renamed files is solved but I think this solution can't establish the link between two versions.

```
Workspace.Merge(sourcePathSpec, targetPath, versionFrom, versionTo, lockLevel,MergeOptionsEx.Baseless);
```

Comment: `the state of the renamed files in the source version is changed to create a branch in the destination version.`  Could you explain more clearly in this part? Renamed files in TFS is just like deleted old files and created a totally new files.

Comment: In TFS for the source version, the file has been renamed in a changeset, when making merge with basless the state of this file becomes create a branch in destination version.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace.Merge Method is used merges the source to the target.

[MergeOptionsEx](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) is a set of merge options.

When you set the `MergeOptionsEx.Baseless` which instructs the server to perform a baseless merge between items.

In TFVC, you could only  **merge to directly related branches**(parent or child).

To pefer a baseless merge, such as use **[tf merge command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.common.mergeoptionsex(v=vs.120).aspx)**.

```
tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive
```

> ***/baseless***
>
> Performs a merge without a base version. That is, allows the user to
>   merge files and folders that do not have a merge relationship. After a
>   baseless merge, **a merge relationship exists**, and future merges do not
>   have to be baseless.
>
> *Note Baseless merges cannot delete files in the target. You can manually carry over such changes.*

`I think this solution can't establish the link between two versions.` What's the detail mean of Link here, did you just mean the merge relationship.  If there is no merge relationship between source and target, you could even not perform the merge with `MergeOptionsEx.None` Enumeration.